# Removing ALL similar answers instead of removing duplicates?

Tags: discussion, answers, exact-duplicates, deleted-answer

I was looking for an answer to the question [How do I copy/paste into VirtualBox?](https://superuser.com/questions/1114819/how-do-i-copy-paste-into-virtualbox/1233496#1233496) I found two such questions here but none contained the answer that I need. After I figured out the answer myself I added it to both questions so users who are directed to either of them can solve their problem.

After that, a moderator has come and has removed both of my answers.

> Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same
>   information really answers both questions, then one question (usually
>   the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can
>   indicate this by voting to close it as a duplicate or, if you don't
>   have enough reputation for that, raise a flag to indicate that it's a
>   duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't
>   just paste the same answer in multiple places.

I understand that the duplicate question and answer have to be removed and referred to the original question. However, what I do not understand, is:

1) Why the moderator can't mark the question as a duplicate himself instead of telling me to do this. Especially given that one of the questions was asked 6 years ago and another 11 months ago, so most likely neither of them will be marked as a duplicate because I don't have enough rights to do it myself.

2) Why did the moderator remove BOTH of my answers? I can't refer to my non-duplicate answer now, as well as can't edit it/add a new answer/flag it for re-adding because "it was deleted by moderator".

What's the point of this? From my perspective, such behavior would discourage users from adding useful answers, so I don't see any reason to do that.

Comment: Neither of your identical answers (which referred to copying files) actually answered the questions asked (which were about enabling the clipboard). If you have a question about copying files, then you can ask and [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer).